# Using MAP and PURR to compute eigen values

Tags: dictionary

I have to compute characteristic roots for 100s of U.S.counties.  I got help using lapply. I prefer using MAP and PURR if that is possible. I am using them to compute linear regressions.
Here is my test problem and the output.

```
 test.dat<- tibble(ID=c(1,2),a=c(1,1),b=c(1,1),c=c(2,2),d=c(4,3))
test.out<-test.dat %>% nest(-ID) %>% mutate(fit = purrr::map(data,~ function(x) eigen(data.matrix(x)), data=.))
```

I would appreciate any help.
Thanks
V.K.Chetty

Comment: Can you add a tag for the programming language you are using?

Comment: @V.K.Chetty - error message?

Comment: desired output?